# is there any option to compare a variable with number and a string in a same if statement using or oprator?

Tags: python

Is there any option to compare a variable with a number and a string in the same if statement using `or` operator?

I already tried this but it's not returning true value:

```
print("enter you choice either 1 for yes\n 2 for no")
x=input("enter your choice")
if(x==1 or x=='yes'):
     x=5
elif(x==2 or x=='no'):
      x=6
print(x)
```

Comment: `if x in {1, 'yes'}`: ... and [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) will return a string, not an integer. so `if x in {'1', 'yes'}` should work here.

Comment: also try,`if x in [1, 'yes']`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`input` returns a string, so you need to compare with the strings.

Also, you can use `in` (`__contains__`) to check for a value in a given collection that implements `__contains__` (could be any primitive collection e.g. `tuple`, `list`, `set`, but using `set` would be efficient due to the *O(1)* lookups, but the cost of creating the collection would be the same for all):

```
if x in {'1', 'yes'}:
```

You can obviously do this using the `or`-chain, but that won't be as readable and maintain-able as using a collection.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
print("enter you choice either 1 for yes\n 2 for no")
x=input("enter your choice")
if(x in {1, '1', 'yes'}):
     x=5
elif(x in {2, '2', 'yes'}):
      x=6
print(x)
```

Python `input` always returns a string in python3. If you are using python2 it could have returned integers. If you simply check for `1` or `'1'` (since for the user they mean the same) it will work on both versions of python

Comment: I din't try this because already figure out the solution although seems right!! btw thanks budd for helping out.

Answer (score 1):

The `input()` function returns a string. So in your case, although the user would input 1 or 2, x would still be a string '1' or '2'. So what you could do is

```
if x in ['1', 'yes']:
   # do something
elif x in ['2', 'no']:
   # do something else
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code and this is the result, the problem was you was comparing a str and int, to fix it you just had to do this.

```
if (x == "1") or (x == "yes")
#code
elif (x == "2") or (x == "no")
```

Comment: Another way is to make the input a float.